# How to increase the image quality in android..?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, decode

I am doing a "Image Editor" like application. I used default camera intent to capture the image. I used to parse the URI and set that to the image view like the following:

```
imgCaptured.setImageURI(Uri.parse(filePath));
```

If I use this raw image, occasionally it is throwing me out of memory error! So I decided to decode the image using the following:

"Got from stackoverflow"

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 8;
    preview_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);


private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 95;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale = 1;
         while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
         && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
         scale *= 2;

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

If I use the decoded image, the output is not in good quality. Some how it seems to be blur. I want a good clear image! After setting it into the ImageView. I need to drag and drop another views.

- How can I achieve the above?
- What is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

what is the reason to divide by 2 in the loop ?
try this

```
while (o.outWidth / scale  >= REQUIRED_SIZE
         && o.outHeight / scale  >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
```

Probably You also would like to  scale the image to the view's size with this method 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, int, int, boolean)

Answer (score 0):

change options.inSampleSize = 8 to options.inSampleSize = 4.

Answer (score 0):

The method which you had used is not complete, you have to add few Math functions to, too maintain the quality of the image.

```
private static Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
            Bitmap b = null;
            final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 100;
            try {
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);
                fis.close();
                int scale = 1;
                if (o.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || o.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
                    scale = (int) Math.pow(
                            2.0,
                            (int) Math.round(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                                    / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth))
                                    / Math.log(0.5)));
                }
                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize = scale;
                fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o2);
                fis.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("Exception in decodeFile() ", e.toString() + "");
            }
            return b;
        }
```

Please let me know, if it worked for you...!!!!:)

Comment: Nope..! It is not working as well. Seems to be very blur.Sorry for being late.